# How do I persist session data from before a redirect?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, redirect

I'm pretty new to PHP and Code Igniter so please forgive any obviously glaring errors.

I'm attempting to redirect a user who logs in to our website based on what is read from the `Permissions` field in the data table containing their information.

I've been able to successfully redirect to the proper controller, but the problem is that as soon as the redirect is done, the Session data is lost, which tells me that's... probably *not* the way I want to be doing this.

Anyway, here's some code -

```
IF ($this->form_validation->run()){ //<---Form validation.
    IF (!$this->User->login( //<---Attempt to log in the user with POST data
        addslashes(strtolower($this->input->post('username', TRUE))), //<-Username
        addslashes($this->input->post('password', TRUE)), //<- Password
        $this->getIP())){ //<-IP
        /*If the login failed stuff goes here bla bla not relevant.*/
    } ELSE {
        SWITCH($this->User->stale('Permissions')){ //<- This works
            CASE 'ADMIN':
                redirect('Admin');
                BREAK;
            /*Some other stuff but not relevant*/
        }
    }
```

I've set a breakpoint in the Admin controller class constructor :

```
CLASS Admin EXTENDS CI_Controller{
    public FUNCTION __construct(){
        PARENT::__construct(); //<-This gets hit.
        $this->load->model('User_Model', 'User'); //<- So does this, but when the $_SESSION value appears in the Variables view, it only has a single value in it.
        $this->User->ID = $this->session->UserID;
        /*Some other stuff that goes here; again, not relevant.*/
    }
}
```

Then there's also where the session data is being set; within the `User_Model` `Login( ... )` method -

```
CLASS User_Model EXTENDS MY_Model{ //<----- MY_Model is just an extension of the CI_Model class that lets me use some of our Database stuff. Testing shows that it all checks out.
    public FUNCTION login($userName, $password, $IP){
        $row = $this->database->get_where('users', ARRAY('UserName' => $userName))->row_array()['UserName'];
        IF (!ISSET($row)){
            /*bla bla bad username handle it.*/
        } ELSE {
            /*Check password against username*/
            IF (/*Stuff*/) {
                /*Bla bla bad password handle it.*/
            } ELSEIF(/*check for already logged in*/){
                /*Bla bla logged in already handle it.*/
            } ELSE {
                /*Login was successful and there was much rejoicing (yaaay) handle it...*/
                /*Then I try and set the session values so that they are accessible after the redirect to the Admin controller:*/
                $this->session->UserID = $row['UserID'];
                /*and many others which aren't persisting*/
            }
        }           
}
```

Again, I'm pretty fresh-faced when it comes to PHP and CodeIgniter; also, I've inherited this project so a lot of what I'm working with is that from which I'm trying to learn, but the individuals responsible for the project I inherited didn't do a very good job with it... getting off track.

My initial inclination is that I am way, *way*, ***way*** off base with my perceived understanding of what the `$_SESSION`, `$this->session` and/or `redirect( ... )` is/are for..

So... what am I doing wrong here? I've asked a question similar to this in which Flash data wasn't persisting but I was able to resolve that because I was redirecting where I shouldn't have been a-redirecting.

So, in order to switch controllers, am I supposed to redirect here? If so, how do I persist the session data set by the login method? I've read somewhere something that suggests to me that the session data needs to be stored on a data table somewhere to be persisted, is that true?

If I'm *not* supposed to be redirecting in this case, how do I switch controllers after I've determined the `Permissions` state of the user after confirming their credentials?

Also - I see in the similar questions section a fairly old question that's pretty much this one. I took a look at it and noticed that I needed to adjust the Config file to handle session information, so I did. I even noticed the directory was created and there are a couple of files present (awesome). However, one file is empty (less awesome) and the other contains nothing of use (least awesome).

This is the `session_configuration` I am running -

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'SomethingSomething_Session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = '/SomethingSomething_Sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

And the Cookies config - (not sure if this is entirely correct either).

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = 'localhost';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

If anyone things anything else would be relevant I'll be happy to share what I can to resolve this issue.

Also, I should note - I am working with Code Igniter 3.0.1.

Comment: I don't know much about how CodeIgniter treats sessions, but I do know that for general PHP, to persist `$_SESSION` data you must use `session_start()` at every single page that you intend to use it.

Comment: @AedixRhinedale A quick search through the code via NP++ shows this call is made within the constructor of the Session.php file. I'll put a breakpoint here and see when it's being called. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Can you check size of data in session, bcz session store info in cookies, which is limited to 4kb.